# UART in Linux: Keep sending for a long time while message is short

Tags: c, uart, linux, terminal

I have written a program which can send and then receive the message just sent from the UART port and I have connected the TXD to RXD together of the same UART port. It has three parts, which are the main function, the function used to open the UART device and the function used to set features of the device. the code are as follows:
The main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
/********************************************************************
       This app can open a serial device which is the first parameter 
delivered to the main function,
and send a string, then, receive it.
version: 1.3

*******************************************************************/








int open_uart(char* port_name);
int UART_initialize(int fd, speed_t speed, int flow_ctrl, int 
data_bits, int stop_bits, int parity );



int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char rev_buff[1023];//read
    char send_buff[1023];//write
    char flag='y';
    int rev_len;
    int send_len;
    fd= open_uart(argv[1]);
    if(fd == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"open serial terminal failed...\n");
        return -1;
    }

    tcflush(fd,TCIOFLUSH);

    UART_initialize(fd,B115200,0,8,1,2);
    while(flag=='y'||flag=='Y')
    {
        printf("Please type in the charactors you want to send~\t:");
        scanf("%s",send_buff);
        fflush(stdin);
        send_len=write(fd,send_buff,strlen(send_buff)+1);
        if(send_len<0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"send failed!\n");
            send_buff[0]='\0';
            continue;
        }
        printf("you have sent:\t%s(%dbytes)\n",send_buff,send_len);
        send_buff[0]='\0';
        tcflush(fd,TCOFLUSH);
        printf("start receive\n");


        rev_len=read(fd,rev_buff,1024);
        tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);
        if(rev_len<0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"receive failed");
            rev_buff[0]='\0';
        }
        else if (rev_len==0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"the port doesn't received any data!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf("you have received:%s\n(%dbytes)",rev_buff,rev_len);
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue?(y/n):");
        scanf("%c",&flag);
        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();  
    }
    close(fd);
}
```

The function used to open the device:

```
/******************************open the 
terminal***********************************
name:   open_uart   
input:  char* port_name: the path to the serial device.
output: file descripter: fd ------> the termianl device.
********************************************************************/
int open_uart(char* port_name)
{
    int fd;//the number standing for the uart port
    //did I open the device successfully 
    fd=open(port_name, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NDELAY);//not block
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("can't open the tty port!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    //whether the device is blocked
    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0) <0)
    {
        printf("fcntl failed!\n");
        return(0);
    }     
    else
    {
        printf("fcntl=%d\n",fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0));
    }
    //whether the device is a tty?
    if(isatty(fileno(stdin))==0)
    {
        printf("standard input is not a terminal device\n");
        return(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("the stnadard input is a  tty!\n");

    }
    printf("fd->tty_device=%d\n",fd);
    return fd;
}
/*********************************************************/
```

The function used to set the features of the device

```
/***********************************************************
name:       UART_initialize
function:   set the number of bits in one data unit, the stoping bit 
and the 
    verifying bit
input:      fd(int): the file descripter pointing to the device
            speed(speed_t):the speed of the termianl
            flow_ctrl: RTS\CTS
            data_bits: the number of the bits in a data unit 7 or 8
            stop_bits: 
            parity:    verifying type
output:     successful: 1   unsuccessful:0


*************************************************/

int UART_initialize(int fd, speed_t speed, int flow_ctrl, int 
data_bits, int stop_bits, int parity)
***************************************
{
    struct termios options;
    if(tcgetattr(fd,&options))
    {
        perror("SetupSerial 1");
        return(0);
    }
    //set bps
    cfsetispeed(&options, speed);
    cfsetospeed(&options, speed);

    ///////

    options.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;

    options.c_cflag |= CREAD;

    switch(flow_ctrl)
    {

        case 0 ://不使用流控制
        options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;break;
        case 1 ://使用硬件流控制
        options.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;break;
        case 2 ://使用软件流控制
        options.c_cflag |= IXON | IXOFF | IXANY;break;
     }

    //set the number of bits
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;//reset the bits mark bits except the 
former ones
    switch(data_bits)
    {
        case 5: options.c_cflag |= CS5;break;
        case 6: options.c_cflag |= CS6;break;
        case 7: options.c_cflag |= CS7;break;
        case 8: options.c_cflag |= CS8;break;
        default: fprintf(stderr,"Unsupported data size\n");
        return 0;
    }   
    //parity bit
    switch(parity)
    {
        case 0:// no parity bit 
            options.c_cflag &=~PARENB;
            options.c_cflag &=~INPCK;
            break;
        case 1://odd number
            options.c_cflag |=(PARODD|PARENB);
            options.c_cflag |=INPCK;
            break;
        case 2://even number
            options.c_cflag |=(PARENB|INPCK);
            options.c_cflag &=~PARODD;
            break;

    } 
    switch(stop_bits)
    {
        case 1://1 stop bit
            options.c_cflag &=~CSTOPB;
            break;
        case 2://2 stop bits
            options.c_cflag |=CSTOPB;
            break;
        default:
           fprintf(stderr,"Unsupported stop bits\n");
           return(0);
    }
    //close special output mode
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    //input mode
    options.c_iflag &=~BRKINT;
    options.c_iflag &=~IGNBRK;//break until NULL

    //wait time and minmum number of "bytes"
    options.c_cc[VTIME]= 1;//wait for 0.1s
    options.c_cc[VMIN]= 1;//read at least 1 byte
    //if flush, receive the data do not read
    tcflush(fd,TCIFLUSH);

    //set options
    if(tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&options)!=0)
    {
        perror("tty set error!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The problem I encountered is that I type a short string into the cmd line, such as "Hello!", the program seemed to "stop" after printing start receiving with the indicator led of txd and rxd keep giving out light. I suppose the device send the string repeatedly. But what exactly cause the problem? Can you help me?

---

Here is my two attempt with the program. In the first attempt, I connect the RXD and TXD together, while in the second attempt I didn't connected them just leaving them suspended. Here is my command line:
[image]
The two attempt both paused at the same place. However, in the first attempt, the sending and receiving LEDs kept being lit up,like this:
[image]

while the LEDs were off after a short lit. Besides, I used oscilloscope and found that in the first attempt, the TXD keeps sending data, while in the second attempt, the TXD just send a very short piece of data then send nothing.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please capitalise sentences, acronyms and capitalisations properly for legibility. Your compiler wouldn't let you away with it. Why should we? You might need to fix your title. Linux doesn't have a UART. I think you mean "C program control of UART ...".

Comment: By the time your code gets to 'start receive' the bytes you sent are long gone. The UART doesn't wait for you to be ready to receive before sending.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? What are these LEDs actually indicating? Maybe the UART LEDs are not "activity" LEDs but only indicate the state of the line.

Comment: @brhans - the code is not dealing with a UART directly, it is dealing with a Serial Port *buffered* by the operating system, so your comment isn't really accurate.

Comment: The use of `tcflush(fd,TCOFLUSH)` seems inappropriate  - unlike Arduino `Serial.flush()` this *discards* rather than *waits* and you haven't allowed time for the message to be transmitted at the serial baud rate, which is far slower than a few lines of code and a `printf()`.  That said, I'm very tempted to vote to close this as off topic as it's really about POSIX serial API's not Electrical Engineering.  The code is also a bit odd - it doesn't look original, but it doesn't look like a sound example either.  You should perhaps start with something else.

Comment: The read function call can block until 1024 bytes are gathered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070731/linux-serial-port-blocking-read-with-timeout

Comment: @filo - not true.  The code here *already* sets `options.c_cc[VMIN]= 1` which is the very subject matter of your link.

Comment: @Transistor-Thank you for pointing it out, I will take care of it in the future.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Thank you for point it out that my question belongs to POSIX serial API and I haven't written any program to control serial terminal so I viewed a few examples and write this code according to my preference. However, I have just started to learn about the serial control API so I am not sure where the problem exits, the hardware or the software. Maybe I should ask this question in stack overflow rather than Electrical Engineering. But I will set up a new question after using the oscilloscope.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Thank you for point out the problem of limited time. I deleted the `tcflush(fd,TCOFLUSH)` and added a`sleep(1);` after `send_len=write(fd,send_buff,strlen(send_buff)+1);` , but the program still "pause" after printing "start receive" with the TXD and RXD LEDs on, which make me very confused. I just can't find out where the problem exits.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I will try the oscilloscope later, probably tomorrow. I use CP210x USB to UART module and the LEDs are off before I type into the data I want to send. The LEDs give out light only after `send_len=write(fd,send_buff,strlen(send_buff)+1);` when I use gdb to run the program step by step. So I think the LEDs indicates the TXD port is sending message.

Comment: @filo - I don't think it is the matter of the parameter "1024" in the read function, because even if the read function read all of the 1024 bytes, it will return after a short time. But my program seems not run after printing "start receive".

Comment: Then print something right after read function to see if it does not block  indefinitely.

Comment: @filo - I added a print right after the read function and it doesn't run. So I think the program does block at read function but I don't know why it blocks.

Comment: Because that is how the stream/socket API works. You have to do some more reading. By default read(1024) means "block my program until you have 1024 bytes".

Comment: @filo - **No, as already pointed out hours ago that is incorrect**.  In actual fact the read function will return when VMIN (which has been set to one character) is received and the interval VTIME (which has been set to 1/10th of a second) has elapsed thereafter.

Comment: You should include the complete input and output of your program in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `tcgetattr(fd,&options)` to fill the options struct, the port may have been opened in canonical mode. Try clearing (or check the state of) this bit:

```
options.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
```

Comment: I disabled canonical mode and it works. Thanks for your helping me to solve my problem which has been disturbing me for a couple of days. In the canonical mode, the RXD didn't receive LF(ASCII: 0x0A), so it paused only to wait for the "end of the line".  Am I right? However, there is still one thing I do not understand. Why do the TXD keeps sending data when connected with the RXD of the same uart port? is it also because of the canonical mode?

Comment: UART TX and RX are totally separate. It makes no difference for the UART if the transmitter is connected to another device or to its own receiver.